# Преобразование XML в HTML через XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть XML

`cinemaXSL.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cinemaToHtml.xsl"?>
<cinema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation ="schema.xsd">
<genres>
    <horror>
        <films>
            <film>
                <name>The exorcist</name>

                    ...etc...
```

И такой файл `cinemaToHtml.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>Cinema</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Something</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

В браузере при открытии xml должнен же выводится заголовок `Something`, но не могу понять почему этого не происходит

В консоли браузера выдаёт `'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.`

Comment: У меня всё работает.  Смотрите консоль сервера и браузера.

Comment: @Ainar-G, а как вы проверяли? Сервера нет, я просто вбиваю полный путь к xml в строке браузера и получаю в консоли  'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

Comment: Проверял с сервером, конечно.  На `file:///` вы каши не сварите, у многих браузеров там ограничения и прочие нестыковки.

Comment: @Ainar-G, у firefox вроде нет таких жёстких ограничений, по крайней мере получилось открыть xml, только вот xsl не сработал, не показало содержимое html, а просто вывело значения полей из xml.

Я сейчас попробую быстренько развернуть сервер, а вы можете подсказать, почему `"каши не сварю на file:///"` ?

Comment: Я не помню всех подробностей.  Пару лет назад начинал с того же, и в итоге достало.  `python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 6060` — и понеслась.

Comment: @Ainar-G, оф, заработало всё прекрасно, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Надо запускать сервер, чтобы верно подгрузились все нужные файлы.

Например, `python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 6060` (`python -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 6060`)

И через него открывать .xml

Спасибо [Ainar-G](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180092/ainar-g) за помощь